# Best way to get an Try[Array[(String,String)]] in Scala

Tags: scala, try-catch

I have a method which takes an index as parameter and returns a `Try[(String,String)]` and I need to execute it for many indices and store result in an array `Try[Array[(String,String)]]`. But the method returns many `Try`, What is the best way to  join all in one `Try[Array[]]`.

```
val index = (0 to 10)
def methodA(index: Int): Try[(String,String)] = Try{("a","b")}
def query(index: Int): Try[(String,String)] = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call each method in turn and `get` the result, and wrap the whole thing in a `Try` to catch the first error:

```
  Try(index.map(methodA(_).get))
```

If any method fails then the `get` with throw an error that will be caught by the outer `Try`.